# Pointwise Convergence and Convergence in the mean of Riemann-integrable functions

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, riemann-integration

> Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of Riemann-integrable functions on $[a, b]$.
>   Assume that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $[a, b]$ and converges in the mean to $g$ on $[a, b]$, where $f$ and $g$ are both continuous. Show that $f = g$.

*($(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges in the mean to g on $[a , b]$ means that $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(f_n, g) = 0$, where $d$ is the $L_2$ metric.)*

I am studying real analysis now and want to prove this statement.
But I don't know how to use condition "$(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges in the mean to g on $[a , b]$." How can I prove this?

Answer (score 5):

Converges in mean implies that there is a subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ such that $f_{n_{k}}(x)\rightarrow g(x)$ pointwise almost everywhere, so $f=g$ a.e. and the continuity eliminates the a.e. condition.

Answer (score 2):

$d_{L_2}(f,g)\leq d_{L_2}(f,f_n)+d_{L_2}(f_n,g)$ by triangular inequality. If you can show that pointwise convergence implies convergence in $L_2$ metric, that is $d_{L_2}(f,f_n)\rightarrow 0$, then you will see $d_{L_2}(f,g)=0$, hence $f=g$ almost everywhere. Can you show

> pointwise convergence implies convergence in $L_2$ metric

Comment: I'm a bit rusty, and this strikes me as something I wouldn't know how to prove, at least without a hint. How do you show that?

Comment: (Specifically, I am a bit skeptical on whether it is true.)

Comment: Isn't it true by DCT, as continuous function on compact set is bounded, and hence $|f_n(t)-f(t)|^2$ is bounded

Comment: That, [indeed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604985/pointwise-convergence-with-boundness-implies-l2-convergence/606359); but presumably, the OP being specifically studying Riemann integration, there is not (yet) a DCT they can use.